# How do I count if in google app scripts with loops?

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not familiarized with GAS. I did a macro in excel VBA and I need to convert it to google app script (I tried the google add-on for converting excel macros to GAS but it give me error).
For reference, this is the table I want to fill with countif with the header values:
[image]

An this is the sheet "Plan duco Q3-Q4" where is the column F with the values I want to Countif for the headers of the first table.
[image]
This is what I got in Excel:

```vb
Sub ContadorEstados()
    Dim TodayDate As Date
    Dim FirstEmptyDate As Date
    Dim counter As Double

    TodayDate = Date
    
'Select the sheet where the table I need to fill with counts is
    Sheets("Ongoing Q3-Q4").Select
    
'Select the last cell with content and offset 1 row to select the first 'empty cell in the C column
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

'We pick the first date that has no values
    FirstEmptyDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    
'Loop, if the first empty date is equal or less than today date we fill the 'data
    If FirstEmptyDate <= TodayDate Then
'counter from 3 (the c column) to 11 (last column with the values i want to '"countif" 
        For counter = 3 To 11
'"Plan Duco Q3-Q4 is another sheet where i hhave the range with the values i 'want to countif

        ActiveCell.Value = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Plan DUCO Q3-Q4").Range("$F$2:$F$150"), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, contador))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is what I got in Gas:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var ssValuesToCount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Plan DUCO Q3-Q4').getRange(2,6,150,1).getValues();

  var ssTable= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ongoing Q3-Q4');

  var ValuesTable = ssTable.getRange(3,3,1,9).getValues();
  var lastrow = ssTable.getRange("B1:B").getValues().filter(String).length +1 ;
  var counter = 0 ;

  for (var i = 0; ValuesTable.length; i++){
    var Values = ValuesTable[0][i]
      for (var j =0; ssValuesToCount.length; j++){
        if (ssValuesToCount[j][0] == Values){
          counter +=1;} 
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: May I ask you to provide what the error is + make it easier for us to catch what the script is doing (tranlate in english) ?

Comment: Hello, I edited the code to make it easier to read in English. I think the VBA code is pretty simple. In the other hand, my try on GAS is just garbage. Please ask me any questions about the VBA code

Comment: Where is `hojaplan` defined?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to find the first empty row based in the value from column C, then compare if the date is equal or less than today date and fill the values from column C to column K of that row with some values you have in another sheet called `Plan DUCO Q3-Q4`, is that correct?

Comment: I've just edited that, it is the sheet where the table to fill with counts is.

Comment: Yes Fernando you are correct, for adding more detail I want to fill the first empty row of the table in the "ongoing Q3-Q4" sheet (column C to column K) with the counts of the headers of that table in column F of "Plan DUCO Q3-Q4" sheet.

Comment: @MarioDiezMartínez I think it would be better if you could share a data sample of the other sheet to understand how the data appears in `Plan DUCO Q3-Q4` to then be copied in `Ongoing Q3-Q4`.

Comment: Hello Fernando, Ive just added the other sheet data for reference.

Comment: I was just checking the info from `Plan DUCO Q3-Q4`, but I do not see any of the data from `Plan DUCO Q3-Q4` being copied in `Ongoing Q3-Q4` according to the first screenshot.